# Как получить "голый" текст, без маски?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки, kotlin

Есть маска текста: `xxx/13xx/xxx`
Есть текст: `222/1300/777`
Как я могу получить текст `22200777` ?

`.replace("/13", "")` отработает криво на примере `222/1300/135`

Comment: Преобразовать маску в регулярку `'(???)/13(??)/(??)'` и использовать выражение замены `'$1$2$3'`.

Comment: Есть способ: `'222/1300/777'.replace('/13', '').replace('/', '')`. Только в нём не используется "маска".

Comment: Или через regex: `import re; re.sub(r'\/|(13)', '', '222/1300/777')`

Comment: @Brainsluggy я указал, что на примере `222/1300/135` будет некорректно отрабатывать

Comment: @NowhereMan любой символ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Через регулярные выражения: заменяем все иксы на `(.)`, дальше матчим как регулярное выражение, вытаскиваем все группы:

```
String mask = "xxx/13xx/xxx";
var pattern = Pattern.compile("^" + mask.replace("x", "(.)") + "$");
String text = "222/1300/777";

var match = pattern.matcher(text);
if (match.find()) {
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i <= match.groupCount(); i++) {
        stringBuilder.append(match.group(i));
    }
    String result = stringBuilder.toString();
    System.out.println(result);
} else {
    System.out.println("Ничего не найдено (строка не соответствует маске)");
}
```

Вывод:

```
22200777
```

Другой вариант - просто идем циклом, сравнивамем символы маски и текста, то что соответствует иксам - добавляем в результат (тут в коде получилось больше валидации, чем какой-то сложной логики):

```
private static String getByMask(String text, String mask) {
    var result = new StringBuilder();

    if (text.length() != mask.length()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Длина текста не соответствует маске");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mask.length(); i ++ ) {
        if (mask.charAt(i) == 'x') {
            result.append(text.charAt(i));
        } else if (mask.charAt(i) != text.charAt(i)) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    String.format("Символ на позиции %d ('%c') не соответствует маске (символ '%c')",
                            i, text.charAt(i), mask.charAt(i)));
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String mask = "xxx/13xx/xxx";
    String text = "222/1300/777";
    System.out.println(getByMask(text, mask));
}
```

Comment: пример с регуляркой - просто шикарен!! можно попросить еще расписать его логику: почему старт цикла с 1? почему символы паттерна должны быть сгруппированы через `(.)`? и тд. работает идеально, но непонятно как)

Comment: Начиная с 1 - потому что первая группа всегда - это весь заматченный текст целиком (в данном случае - "222/1300/777"), а дальше идут группы соответствующие частям обернутым в скобки. Каждую точку оборачиваю в скобки, чтобы каждый отдельный символ соответствующий иксу можно было вытащить как группу. В идеале можно было бы группы рядом идущих иксов оборачивать в скобки, но для этого нужна более сложная логика, а так можно простой заменой икса на `"(.)"` обойтись.

Comment: а почему нельзя использовать `(.){3}` вместо `(.)(.)(.)` ?

Comment: @Wlad `(.{3})`. Можно, но придется считать идущие подряд иксы, для этого нужна более сложная логика, выгода от такого улучшения не очевидна. См. последнее предложение в моем предыдущем комментарии. Проще тогда уже будет саму маску в виде регулярного выражения переписать.

Comment: так и есть. эту маску я сам руками писать буду. сделал `"^(\\d{3})/13(\\d{2})/(\\d{3})$"` - все работает как часы! очень красивое решение! большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Варианты с использованием Stream API и методами `Matcher::results()` / `Matcher::replaceAll()`

1. Аналог предложенного решения:

- символы `x` в маске превращаются в группы `(.)`
- при совпадении для каждой группы берётся её значение по номеру

```java
public static String checkMask1(String mask, String val) {
    return Pattern.compile(mask.replaceAll("x", "(.)"))
        .matcher(val)
        .results() // Stream<MatchResult>
        .flatMap(mr -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, mr.groupCount())
            .mapToObj(i -> mr.group(i)) 
        ) // Stream<String>
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
}

При несоответствии шаблона возвращается пустая строка.
```

2. Вариант похожий на решение от @Akina в комментариях:

- Аналогично строится паттерн, в котором `x` меняется на `(.)`
- Строится выражение для замены всех `x` на "$1$2...$N" с использованием `Matcher::replaceAll`, все символы не-`x` удаляются.
- Используется "обычная" замена в строке

```java
public static String checkMask2(String mask, String val) {
    int[] ix = {1};

    return val.replaceFirst(
        mask.replaceAll("x", "(.)"),
        Pattern.compile("x").matcher(mask.replaceAll("[^x]", ""))
            .replaceAll(mr -> "\\$"+ix[0]++)
    );
}
```

При несоответствии шаблона возвращается исходная строка

```java
String[] tests = {"222/1300/777", "222/1400/777"};
for (String t : tests) {
    System.out.println(t + " -> '" + checkMask1("xxx/13xx/xxx", t) + "'");
    System.out.println(t + " -> '" + checkMask2("xxx/13xx/xxx", t) + "'");
}
```

```
222/1300/777 -> '22200777'
222/1300/777 -> '22200777'
222/1400/777 -> ''
222/1400/777 -> '222/1400/777'
```